# Nuxt / Vue.js in TypeScript: Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'components' does not exist in type 'VueClass'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error message when I use a decorator with components and middleware:

[image]

Upon inspection, the error reads:
`TS2345: Argument of type '{ components: { Test: typeof Nav; }; middleware: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'components' does not exist in type 'VueClass'. Did you mean to write 'component'?`

[image]

Without middleware, the @Component decorator no longer fusses:

[image]

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see that `middleware` is a [property defined by Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/) and isn't a standard Vue property.

The error message is a little bit misleading - it looks like it's saying the problem is with the `components` property, but what it's actually saying is that an object with *both* `{components: ..., middleware: ...}` doesn't match any of the expected types.

**The solution:**

What you need to do is update the definition of the Vue `ComponentOptions` type to add the `middleware` property.

To do this, create a new `.d.ts` file (or edit an existing type file e.g. `references.d.ts`) and add this declaration to it:

```
// references.d.ts
/**
 * Extends interfaces in Vue.js
 */

import Vue, { ComponentOptions } from "vue";

declare module "vue/types/options" {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    // This adds the `middleware` property to the existing `vue/types/options/ComponentOptions` type
    middleware?: string | string[];
  }
}
```

This is just a variation on how the Vuex plugin adds the `store` property to the Vue component type. See the [`vuex/types/vue.d.ts` source](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts)) for how this is done.