# How to use middleware, asyncData, fetch in Nuxt.js v2 with typescript and Option API

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working hard to introduce typescript to Nuxt.js with Option API.

In Current Code, we use `middleware`, `asyncData` and `fetch` methods.
After I switched lang to `ts` (`<script lang="ts">`), typescript says error for the above methods.

like this (about `middleware`)

```
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'middleware' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, DefaultProps>'.
```

Then, I googled this problem and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090772/15553908), but it does not work maybe because this solution is about Nuxt with Class API...

summary of my `.vue` file:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  async middleware({store, params, from}) {
    // Error is occuring here...
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'middleware' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<DefaultProps>, DefaultProps>'.
  },
  asyncData({params}) {
    ~~~
  },
});
</script>
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to use those methods in Nuxt with Option API ?

Comment: I found this error is said by 'Vetur', but I'm not sure about this can be helpful for resolving this probrem...

Comment: After I restarting Vetur, I solved it !!!